# PECL SSH2 Installation issue

Tags: ssh, installation, centos, pecl

I am running this command:

```
sudo pecl install ssh2
```

It resulting the following log and exit with an error:

```
libssh2 prefix? [autodetect] :
building in /var/tmp/pear-build-rootHyRX5L/ssh2-0.12
running: /var/tmp/ssh2/configure --with-ssh2
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for cc... cc
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking whether we are cross compiling... no
checking for suffix of executables...
checking for suffix of object files... o
checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
checking for icc... no
checking for suncc... no
checking whether cc understands -c and -o together... yes
checking for system library directory... lib
checking if compiler supports -R... no
checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
checking build system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking host system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking target system type... x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
checking for PHP prefix... /usr
checking for PHP includes... -I/usr/include/php -I/usr/include/php/main -I/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/Zend -I/usr/include/php/ext -I/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib
checking for PHP extension directory... /usr/lib64/php/modules
checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /usr/include/php
checking if debug is enabled... no
checking if zts is enabled... no
checking for re2c... no
configure: WARNING: You will need re2c 0.13.4 or later if you want to regenerate PHP parsers.
checking for gawk... gawk
checking for ssh2 support... yes, shared
checking for ssh2 files in default path... not found
configure: error: The required libssh2 library was not found.  You can obtain that package from http://sourceforge.net/projects/libssh2/
ERROR: `/var/tmp/ssh2/configure --with-ssh2' failed
```

As you can see it says, it can't find libssh2. However, when I run the command:

```
sudo yum install libssh2
```

It says that it is already installed:

```
Setting up Install Process
Package libssh2-1.4.2-1.el6.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Now, I am assuming, for some reason, pecl installer can't find the libssh2 installation. How can I give it recognize that path. Is there any easy alternative way to get it done properly?

Answer (score 1):

you might have better luck if you just used phpseclib, a pure PHP SSH client, to emulate libssh2:

https://github.com/phpseclib/libssh2-compatibility-layer

Comment: Actually, I need it to connect via composer , so this php library won't work for me in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I did `yum install libssh2-devel` and then `sudo pecl install ssh2-0.12` and worked.